# How to save a string to XML in VBA?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, api, http

I am trying to export the value in "body" to an XML file so I can clearly see what the compiled data looks like before sending in the HTTP request

How do I go about doing that?

Here is my code:

```
Sub API_Test()

 body = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & _
        "<orders xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">" & _
        "<order>" & _
        "<orderid>" & Range("A1") & "</orderid>" & _
        "<operation>" & Range("A2") & "</operationtype>" & _
        "</orderid>" & _
        "</order>" & _
        "</orders>"

 Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
 URL = "http://www.server.com/"
 objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "version", "000"
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "authenticate", "000"
 objHTTP.send (body)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, I've reworded  the question per the guidelines, I'd greatly appreciate for someone to review!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`ADODB.Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032.aspx) object to save the string to a file.  See [Read & Write UTF-8 Files](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/read_write_utf8/).  For example:

```
Dim objStream
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.CharSet = "Windows-1255"
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText body
objStream.SaveToFile "C:\path\file.xml", 2
```

I don't know why you would want to use Windows-1255, though.  You are not sending any Hebrew characters, and you would have to change the XML's prolog to match:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1255"?>
```

UTF-8 would be better to use, and it is fully compatible with Hebrew:

```
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

Comment: resolved, thanks alot! It actually had Chinese characters and I thought I'd need to use a Chinese encoding but utf-8 did the job

Comment: By the way, how do I use the objHTTP.send with a filepath? I mean I want to send a complete XML file, I tried  objHTTP.send(filepath/file.xml) but it didn't work for some reason

Comment: You need to either 1) open the file, read it into a byte array, and then send the array, or 2) wrap the file access in an object that implements `IStream` and then send the object.

Comment: Have a look at [SHCreateStreamOnFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759864.aspx).

Comment: Resolved all, thanks so much!